# NuxtJS with apollo returns connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, api-platform.com

I'm trying to setup Apollo GraphQL with NuxtJS and APIPlatform

This is my nuxt.config.js :

```
  apollo: {
    defaultOptions: {
      $query: {
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        errorPolicy: "all"
      }
    },
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: process.env.API_GRAPHQL || 'http://localhost:8080/api/graphql'
      }
    }
  }
```

A component example :

```
export default {
  name: "myComponentExample",
  apollo: {
    allLastsDatas: {
      prefetch: true,
      query: lastsDatasQuery,
    }
  }
}
```

But, I have this error :

> Network error: request to http://localhost:8080/api/graphql failed,
> reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

The fact is, when I'm running this query with GraphiQL, or Postman, or in async methods (with this.$apollo.query...) I don't have this error...

So, I checked my Nginx proxy (which is upstream of my PHP GraphQL endpoint), but I don't know why I have this error...

```
server {
    server_name ~.*;
    root /usr/src/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST|PATCH|DELETE)") {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" '*' always;
        }

        # Preflighted requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" '*' always;
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
            return 200;
        }

        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/src/app/public/index.php;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```